How do I solve no valid small icon error when using awesome_notifications package in flutter?
I have set the icon to null so as to use the app icon as per instructions in the docs but I am still getting this error. What else can I do?
E/flutter ( 4670): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(NOTIFICATION_THREAD_EXCEPTION, Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(channel=high_importance_channel pri=2 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null tick defaults=0x0 flags=0x19 color=0xff000000 actions=1 vis=PRIVATE), unexpectedError, null)
